# SQL - Select first n row where next n Row values are sequential + 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with row ID and Cct numbers. The Cct column can be +1 sequential depending on the preceeding select statement.

I want to find the first row where the next n rows cct no. increments + 1 to n-1.

Sample

```
ID    Cct
1      1
2      3
7      5
8      6
10     9
11     10
12     11
```

if n = 2 I want to select row with ID 7 because it is the first time that the next n rows cct value are value + 1

if n = 3 I want to select row with ID 10 as the next n-1 rows are incremented by + 1

Hope this is clear

Comment: I don't follow the logic of what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get it.  You are looking for lengths of sequences in the data, where a sequence is incremented by 1.

You can identify them using `row_number()` and subtraction -- the difference is fixed for a sequence.

So:

```
select top 1 min(id), count(*) as length
from (select s.*, (cct - row_number() over (order by id)) as grp
      from sample s
     ) s
group by grp
having count(*) >= @n
order by min(id)
```

This gets the first time that a sequence of length (at least) `@n` appears in the data.

Comment: This is correct. I have one more criteria I didn't consider. The minimum cct value just satisfy the following `(cct + 2) % 3 = 0` . Is this achievable?

Comment: @user1781272 . . . I don't see how that fits into the question, unless you just want to add a `where` clause to the subquery.  Otherwise, ask another question with sample data and an explanation of the problem.

Comment: @user1781272 I have understood what you are looking for, I have answered this question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836248/select-first-row-where-next-2-rows-increment-by-1-and-rowval-2-is-divisibl/38205347#38205347)